# Autocomplete in Jupyter notebook not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have tried the following steps after the installation of Anaconda's latest version. I am not able to get the autocomplete feature working...

Any suggestions on what else I need to try...

Step 1
 1) pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
 2) pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
 3) jupyter contrib nbextension install --user 
 4) jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user

Step 2: Open jupyter notebook
 - click on nbextensions tab
 - unckeck disable configuration for nbextensions without explicit compatibility
 - put a check on Hinterland

Comment: Why not use Conda instead of pip to install the package, since you’re already using the former for the environment?

Comment: auto-complete should work using the tab key not automatically.

Comment: have you tried to run 'ipython' command and type import num and then click tab. is it working or not?

Comment: Also, try to run the following inside the notebook '%config IPCompleter'. what is the output?

Comment: finally, try '%config IPCompleter.greedy=True' and '%config IPCompleter.use_jedi=False' . try all the combinations of true and false for these two configurations

Comment: 1. The tab does not autocomplete

Comment: 2. The out put.. How do I send the data across ?

Comment: 3. The greedy command also does not work...

Comment: Any further help from anyone. The tab autocomplete is also not working....

Comment: Sorry sir, these suggestions did not work as well.I have reinstalled the version. Ironically, the Anaconda distribution I installed on my laptop has the autocomplete working perfectly

Answer (score 18):

I was also having this problem. I fixed it by disabling **jedi**:

```
# Disable jedi autocompleter
%config Completer.use_jedi = False
```

Comment: Worked for me with jupyter installed in python3.6 venv!

Comment: where is this config?

Comment: It is a magic command from IPython (see the documentation [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-config))

Comment: After installing Jedi and ipython, I run the code snippet command: **%config IPCompleter.greedy=True** But this didn't worked. 
Then above answer worked for me, by creating a new Jupyter Notebook or opening an existing one and typing the above code snippet in a cell

Answer (score 6):

One of the reasons behind this issue can be the crashes of kernel when you try to use the autocompletion. I faced this issue and by observing the logs generated in the terminal used to open jupyter found that every time I try to use the autocompleter, kernel crashes. with the following solution, I resolved the issue in macOs 11.1 Big Sur.

You can just set the Ipython to use something else rather than jedi to do the completion task like pyreadline which can be installed by `pip3 install pyreadline` . But first you have to disable jedi in the Ipython kernel with the following command:

> %config IPCompleter.use_jedi = False

This command will resolve the issue in the current session and if you want to change this configuration in the config file of Ipython kernel you can use the following commands:

> ipython profile create

making a new config file for the ipython in the following directory:
`/Users/zhivarsourati/.ipython/profile_default`

and you can append the following line to the file `ipython_kernel_config.py` generated with the previous command:

> c.IPCompleter.use_jedi = False

Answer (score 2):

Out of frustration,
I moved to Spyder 4.0.1 and installed Kite.

Been quite frustrating...

Comment: kite is not freee anymore

Comment: Kite is definitely a new mighmare ://

Answer (score 0):

Go to nbextensions and disable other autocomplete codes.
In my case TabNine was the issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43ztR.png)