# Disable Jedi - no ipython_config.py?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython

I have Anaconda distribution of Python on Windows.

I have issues with auto-complete in Jupyter Notebook.

I think auto-complete was working before but it doesn't quite work now. I don't get it.

So I am trying to disable Jedi as it messes up my auto-complete in Jupyter Notebook (that's what other folks say who had the same issue).

This is described on several web pages as a possible solution.

See also
[Kernel taking too long to autocomplete (tab) in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186370/kernel-taking-too-long-to-autocomplete-tab-in-jupyter-notebook)

I follow this suggestion

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10493#issuecomment-298968328

I can locate my profile directory but there's no `ipython_config.py` there.

```
C:\Users\username\.ipython> dir ipython_config.py /s
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is BC61-492E
File Not Found

C:\Users\username\.ipython>
```

Why so? What am I missing?

Should I create the file myself if it's missing?

Maybe under the **profile_default** subfolder of `C:\Users\username\.ipython`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autocomplete in Jupyter notebook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131686/autocomplete-in-jupyter-notebook-not-working)

Comment: @dm2 Yes, kind of. I didn't know that I had to run `ipython profile create` first, and then append that property `c.IPCompleter.use_jedi = False` Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need it on the fly for a single notebook in jupyter:

```
%config IPCompleter.use_jedi=False
```

does the magic trick, too.

Answer (score 0):

If the file ipython_config.py is missing then:

1. Run `ipython profile create` in the `profile_default` sub-folder
2. Append this property `c.IPCompleter.use_jedi = False`
   to the newly created `ipython_config.py` file