# How to remove this auto generated grey text in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

That code in grey randomly comes up on its own and whenever I click on the cell it disappears. If I click on the right arrow the grey code turns black.

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda. Please help.

[Example of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5QdR.png)

Comment: Have you tried turning off auto-complete? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68085330/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131686/autocomplete-in-jupyter-notebook-not-working). It's meant to be a feature to save you from typing.

Comment: So after a lot of hit and trials I realized it was actually a chrome extension which was hampering with the jupyter environment. Removing the extension worked